# remotely debugging a server/client application with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging

The to start my server/client I pass the client as a command line argument to the server and both processes are startet.

`java -cp bin this.is.an.example.server "java -cp C:\this\is\another\example\bin\client main.Client"`

in an attempt to debug it comfortably I installed eclipse by adding the client in the servers run configurations as an argument. It worked. Unfortunately this way I only able to debug the server. I had no way to access the client during runtime as it runs in another process.

So I started searching for a solution and found some tutorials like this for example [tutorial_1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/index.html)

I added to my command line `java -cp bin this.is.an.example.server "java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:56111,suspend=y -cp C:\this\is\another\example\bin\client main.Client"`

To my client in eclipse I added, like figure 6 in the tuttorial, a remote-debug confuguration.

When I debug in eclipse it says

> Waiting for vm to connect to port 56111

but nothing happens.

So here are my problems:

1. am I doing it the right way? or is there another, maybe simplier way to debug my client? Any suggestions?
2. if remote debugging is fine. is it possible to start remote debugging by passing the argument to my server which then starts the client with 
   `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);`?

Comment: It seems really awkward that you start client and server **together**. The whole idea of a client/server architecture is that those two are independent from each other. So I would question your very first sentence. Instead: you start your server. Then you start your client; and you give IP address and port number of the server to the client; so that it then can connect to that server. Of course, for initial testing, IP and port are always the same, so it should be straight forward to setup a runtime configuration for your client in eclipse.

Comment: Besides: installing and using eclipse **just for launching** java projects sounds like **overkill**. You should either do **all your development work" from eclipse; or not use it at all. If you are more on the "I want to learn how to do things without an IDE" ... then you could write a few starter scripts to start client/server ....

Comment: yes indeed it is awkward but I inherited it this way and have now to find a way to make it work, .. again. supposedly it was/is working. I called it server client because the main program is acting like a "server" managing communication beween all "clients" and btw I didn't install eclipse to launch the "server/client" but to debug it there were some other issues as well

Comment: Honestly, I've always though that in *address* field there should be only port. 

In contexts where a client is attaching to a server, socket transport addresses have the format "<name>:<port>" where <name> is the host name and <port> is the socket port number at which it attaches or listens. In contexts where a server is waiting for a client to attach, the address consists of the port number alone (the host name is implicit).
From: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/conninv.html#Transports

Comment: You inherited it. Does that mean ... is it **yours** now? That is a very fundamental question. You see, if you are now **responsible** for this thing, do you want to be responsible for something that is broken from the beginning? Or would it make sense to step back; and fix such fundamental issues before investing more time? Maybe yes, maybe no. Just trying to create some awareness on your side to consider your **true** most important priorities.

Comment: yes I'm resposible for it now, I'm not very happy with it, thats clear but I'm giving it a fair shot investigating if it is worth more time, which acutually costs time. Like you said maybe yes maybe no

Comment: @gmaslowski yes I tried to start my "client" as a debug server, thats why I added added the: java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket, address=127.0.0.1:56111,suspend=y, ... to the clients invocation in eclipse I start my remote debugging by listening for port 56111

Comment: @aldr: read my answer.

Comment: @gmaslowski no. I want wo debug the client. when I start the server in eclipse with th debug Icon no problem there

Comment: @aldr: java -cp bin this.is.an.example.server "java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=56111,suspend=y -cp C:\this\is\another\example\bin\client main.Client"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/conninv.html#Transports

> In contexts where a client is attaching to a server, socket transport
>   addresses have the format ":" where  is the host
>   name and  is the socket port number at which it attaches or
>   listens. In contexts where a server is waiting for a client to attach,
>   the address consists of the port number alone (the host name is
>   implicit).

And:

> *name*: address
>
> *required*: yes, if server=n  no, otherwise
>
> *default value*: ""
>
> *description*: Transport address for the
>   connection. If server=n, attempt to attach to debugger application at
>   this address. If server=y, listen for a connection at this address.

From my understanding with such invocation:

```
java -cp bin this.is.an.example.server "java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:56111,suspend=y -cp C:\this\is\another\example\bin\client main.Client"
```

the client app has the configuration to try to connect to 127.0.0.1:56111. And from what I understood you'd like to debug the server, so I think you should change the invocation to:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=56111,suspend=y -cp bin this.is.an.example.server "java -cp C:\this\is\another\example\bin\client main.Client"
```

However if the client app should be listening for connections it should be like that:

```
java -cp bin this.is.an.example.server "java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=56111,suspend=y -cp C:\this\is\another\example\bin\client main.Client"
```

Consider also changing -Xrunjdwp to -agentlib:jwdp if Java >= 5.0.